# Assign a function output prints to a variable in python

Tags: python, terminal, output

I have a function (in some project) that it prints the result.when I call it from the command line or in another python project, it prints the output on the terminal. But I want to store all the print result in a variable, something like this:

```
output = function_name(function_args)
```

and instead of printing the results on the terminal I want to store them in the `output` variable.
also, the main function returns something(just a number as the status) as the result which i do not want that number.

Comment: Why don't you fix the function to return the result instead of printing?

Comment: It may be this is in library code which the user cannot modify.  Give the benefit of the doubt!

Comment: @wim for my own curiosity, when does this arise? Just that a company doesn't allow it, or is there a practical limitation somewhere inherent to python?

Comment: There are many possible cases - sometimes you just have python interfaces which wrap  `.so` file (compiled code).  Sometimes there are .pyc-only distributions as a (weak) attempt obfuscate the source code.  Sometimes the code *should* print to stdout, and you need to capture the value in your tests, you don't modify the code under test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by rebinding `sys.stdout`:

```
>>> def foo():
...     print('potato')
... 
>>> import sys, io
>>> sys.stdout = io.StringIO()
>>> foo()
>>> val = sys.stdout.getvalue()
>>> sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__  # restores original stdout
>>> print(val)
potato
```

For a nicer way to do it, consider writing a context manager.  If you're on Python 3.4+, it's [already been written for you](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.redirect_stdout).

```
>>> from contextlib import redirect_stdout
>>> f = io.StringIO()
>>> with redirect_stdout(f):
...     foo()
... 
>>> print(f.getvalue())
potato
```

In the case that you are able to modify the function itself, it may be cleaner to allow a dependency injection of the output stream (this is just a fancy way of saying "passing arguments"):

```
def foo(file=sys.stdout):
    print('potato', file=file)
```

Answer (score 0):

The sensible solution is simple and obvious: fix the function so that it returns the correct data instead of printing it. Else you *can* use the hack posted by wim but assuming you have the hand on the faulty function resorting to such a convoluted solution falls into the "WTF" category.

NB of course if you don't have the hand on the function's code or it's just for a 5 minutes one-shot script, capturing `sys.stdout` is a handy fallback.